# Real time math Web form

Tags: html, forms, dynamic, real-time

I apologize in advance for such a basic question, but searching Google keeps returning largely irrelevant answers.

I want to make a web form that does realtime math. That simple. For example I type 5 into a box and immediately 20 appears in a box below it. This is because it is multiplying it by 4 on the fly. I erase the 5 and replace with a 20 and boom, there's an 80.

I believe that after I have this building block I can do two things: Make a real time price sheet (i.e.. Apple Online Store click a box and the price changes in real time) and do automatic contract math for us personally.

Comment: How should the application know about the *4*? Is it a constant value? Independently of that, here are two keywords you can search for in your favorite search engine: **AJAX**, **keyup event/DOM events**.

Comment: read up on "keyup" events.

Comment: Sounds you want some info on Javascript DOM manipulation - if so, I would recommend reading some jQuery tutorials.

Comment: I've included links for you in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you'll need to name the text box like so:

```
Math:<input type="text" id="MathTB"/>
```

[Here's the reference website for the jQuery "Keyup" function](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/)

[and the ID selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

```
var mathTextBox = $("#MathTB");  
mathTextBox.keyup(function () {
    var value = mathtextbox.val();
    value *= 4;
    mathTextBox.val(value);
});
```

Using jquery, this should get you where you're trying to go.

Please continue to use that site as a first resource, and you will be an expert in no time.